# Will Allah forgive a muslim who used to claim that he is allah?

Tags: quran, allah

Will allah forgive a muslim who used to claim that he is allah or no? If thr muslim did a sincere repentance will allah forgive him??

Answer (score 1):

Say, "O My servants who have transgressed against themselves [by sinning], do not despair of the mercy of Allah. Indeed, Allah forgives all sins.1 Indeed, it is He who is the Forgiving, the Merciful." [ Az:Zumar:53]

Allah will forgive any sin if he wills.
Infact, it is haram for you to think that you have committed a sin that Allah will not forgive.
Allah is Ar-Rahman Ar-Raheem Al-Ghafoor,

And Allah knows best